# Ongoing-number as first multiindex in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, group-by, multi-index

In a grouped (by `id`) data frame `df`

```
id, last_name, first_name
sdfg, Muller, Peter
fgjh, Smith, Rob
fgjh, Smith, Robert
hjsa, Jackson, Michael
```

I want to add another index `person` at the very beginning as an ongoing number, so that we'll get

```
person, id, last_name, first_name
0, sdfg, Muller, Peter
1, fgjh, Smith, Rob
1, fgjh, Smith, Robert
2, hjsa, Jackson, Michael
```

I tried to use `reset_index(...)`, but this sets an ongoing number regardless of the grouping.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
df.set_index((~df.index.duplicated()).cumsum()-1, append=True).swaplevel()

#         last_name  first_name
#   id                         
# 0 sdfg     Muller       Peter
# 1 fgjh      Smith         Rob
#   fgjh      Smith      Robert
# 2 hjsa    Jackson     Michael
```

This approach works by negating the result of `df.index.duplicated` and taking the cumulative sum (minus 1) to generate an array that increments each time the value in the index changes. It then adds it to your existing index with `set_index` and `append=True`, before finally using `swaplevel` so that the `id` portion of your new MultiIndex is at level 1.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!